# Odoo 10 mass mailing configure bounces

Tags: python, email, odoo, odoo-10

I'm using Odoo 10 mass mailing module to send newsletters. I have configured it but I don't know how to configure bounced emails. It is registering correctly sent emails, received (except that it is registering bounced as received), opened and clicks.

Can anyone please help me?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. Just configured the 'bounce' system parameter to an email with the same name.

Example:

I created an email bounce-register@example.com. Also remember to configure the alias domain in your general settings to 'example.com'

After configuring your email to register bounces you need to configure an incomming mail server for this email (I configured it as an IMAP so I think that should do altough you can also configure it as a POP). That would be it.

Hope this info server for you